# Bind Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab in tmux

Tags: linux, putty, tmux, xterm

I'm trying to a get a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> binding to work inside of a tmux session (I'm also using PuTTY).

I already went through the pains of having to recompile PuTTY so it would send <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>  correctly. After using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, and I'm able to see that `^[[27;5;9~` and `^[[27;6;9~` are being sent for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, respectively. Is there any way I can get these bound to next-window and previous-window inside of tmux?

Edit:
After some research, I'm thinking I might have to configure xterm to include those keycodes. Any idea how I would go about doing that?

Edit2:
So I found out I can retrieve infocmp and recompile it. I added

`kctab=\E[27;5;9~, kcstab=\E[27;6;9~,`

to the end of it, except now it's giving me an error. "**entry does not start with terminal names in column one**"

Comment: Instructions for how to recompile PuTTY with Ctrl-Tab support. http://scnr.net/blog/index.php/archives/61

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Recent “unreleased” versions of *tmux* do automatically recognize those xterm-style key sequences once you have your terminal sending them (no need to change your terminfo entry). The next release version (1.8?) should also have this support. With an appropriate build of *tmux*<sup>1</sup>, all you have to do is bind the keys in your *tmux* configuration:

```
bind-key C-Tab next-window
bind-key C-S-Tab previous-window
```

You will still need to type your prefix key before these keys.

(Note: `~/.tmux.conf` is only processed when the server starts. If you make changes to it, you will either need to exit all your sessions and restart the server, or use (e.g.) `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf` to have your existing server re-process the file.)

Also, if you want *tmux* to pass along these (and other) xterm-style key sequences to programs running inside *tmux*, then you will need to enable the `xterm-keys` window option.

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
```

(If you prefer, you can do this on a per-window basis by using `-w` instead of `-gw`.)

---

If you want to be able to use those keys without typing the prefix, then you can use “no prefix” bindings instead:

```
bind-key -n C-Tab next-window
bind-key -n C-S-Tab previous-window
```

This will more or less “dedicate” the keys to *tmux*, though. It will be difficult to type these keys to any program running inside *tmux* (e.g. you would have to use the *tmux* command `send-keys C-Tab`—as normal, `xterm-keys` must be enabled to send these xterm-style key sequences).

---

The problem with your terminfo entry editing is probably because each line after the one that names the terminal type needs to start with a Tab. Lines that do not start with a tab are the beginning of a new terminal entry. Technically, the NL TAB sequence is basically a line continuation in this file format; each entry is a single logical line.

Also, if you are redefining terminfo entries, be sure to use `-x` with *infocmp* and *tic* to preserve the user-defined capabilities (some of which are fairly standard).

---

<sup>1</sup> I.e. built from recent code in the [*tmux* Git repository at sf.net](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/) (at the clone-able URL `git://git.code.sf.net/p/tmux/tmux-code`).

Comment: tmux doesn't recognize C-Tab and C-S-Tab as valid keys (says it is an unknown key).And thanks for the heads up, I reverted my terminfo changes because to be honest, I didn't really know what I was doing.

Comment: Oops, C-Tab (and C-S-Tab) are recognized in my build of *tmux*, but that feature is not part of the latest release (1.7). If you build a recent version of the not-yet-released code (i.e. from git://git.code.sf.net/p/tmux/tmux-code), then it will support these keys. Sorry about the confusion! I will update the answer text to describe this situation.

Comment: as a note, you can reload tmux config on the fly. :source-file ~/.tmux.conf if in tmux, or you can bind it.

Comment: another note for fast reloading `bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"` so I reload the settings with a prefix + Ctrl-r

Comment: I am on a WSL terminal, with tmux version 2.8, and it's not working. Ctrl-Tab doesn't do anything. I configure the Keys options on the terminal app to not use the Ctrl-Tab/ Shift-Tab shortcuts, but that doesn't work either. When I do `prefix + C-Tab`, tmux shows `:.5I` on the status line, while `prefix + C-S-Tab` shows `:.6I`. Not sure if that's a clue for something.

Answer (score 0):

If your key binds don't work on Windows Terminal/WSL, that is:

```
bind -r C-Tab next-window
bind -r C-S-Tab previous-window
```

You need to go to the terminal key bind settings and add mappings for the tab with modifiers. For Windows Terminal it will be `Setting`->`Open JSON file`->go to `"actions"`->and add the following:

```
{
    "command":
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "\u001b[27;5;9~"
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+tab"
},
{
    "command":
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "\u001b[27;6;9~"
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+shift+tab"
},
```

You can check Unicode mappings for key binds in Linux with the app `showkey -a`. It does not work too well for the tab though, so for other modifiers for the tab check how the code changes for example for `PageUp` with modiefiers.