# Overriding tmux shortcuts

Tags: terminal, tmux

Is it possible to change `tmux` shortcuts such that:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> opens new window
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> closes a window
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> cycles through a list of windows
4. other similar shortcuts for splitting horizontally / vertically

I really like its features but am always of the opinion that the less shortcut I have to learn the better.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems like you want to do this without the command prefix key. If that's correct, add the following commands to your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind-key -n C-t new-window
bind-key -n C-w kill-window
bind-key -n C-Tab next-window
```

If you want to use the prefix key, then drop the `-n` from the above commands.

Comment: Excellent! The first two works but for some reason it doesn't detect the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: It seems that I need to have a specific build of xterm that sends the Tab key sequence so that tmux can detect it, according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470001/bind-ctrltab-and-ctrlshifttab-in-tmux)

Comment: @lolski vim-like `Ctrl + H` and `Ctrl + L` to change windows is another option.